# Python - 2 lists

Tags: python

I am trying to making a word translator.

```
english_List = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_List = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento",]
```

Would I be able to make it so when enter an English word e.g. `"fire"` it will print out the corresponding translation `"fuego"`?

Comment: Yes, you would. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You should consider using a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary. You can make a dictionary where an English word is mapped
to the corresponding Spanish word from these 2 lists using `zip()` to couple `"fire"` with `"fuego"`, `"apple"` with `"manzana"` and so forth. Then build a dictionary using the `dict()`.

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento"]

english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))
```

You can get a translation for English word then as:

```
spanish = english_to_spanish['apple']
```

If a word is not found, `KeyError` exception is raised. A more complete example could use a function for translation, say:

```
def translate(english_word):
    try:
        print("{} in Spanish is {}".format(
            english_word, english_to_spanish[english_word]))
    except KeyError:
        print("Looks like Spanish does not have the word for {}, sorry"
            .format(english_word))

while True:
    word = input()  # raw_input in python 2
    translate(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict to map the corresponding words:

```
trans_dict = {"fire":"fuego","apple":"manzana","morning":"mañana","river":"río","wind":"viento"}

inp = raw_input("Enter your english word to translate:").lower()
print("{} is {}".format(inp.capitalize(),trans_dict.get(inp," not in my translation dict").capitalize()))
```

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to make the dict from your lists:

```
english_List = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_List = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento"]
trans_dict = dict(zip(english_List,spanish_List))
```

Using `trans_dict.get(inp,"not in my translation dict")` with a default value of `"not in my translation dict"` will make sure if the user enters a word the does not exist in our `trans_dict`, it will print the `the_word is not in my translation dict"` and avoid a `keyError`

We use `.lower()` in case the user enter Fire or Apple etc.. with an uppercase letter and use `str.capitalize()` for the output the data capitalized.

[dict.get](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)

Comment: If you're going to answer this, you might as well include how they can build a `dict` from their existing lists...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this function:

```
def translate(word, english_list, spanish_list):
    if word in english_list:
        return spanish_list[english_list.index(word)]
    else:
        return None
```

However, the proper way would be to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use a dictionary.
For example:

```
d = {"fire": "fuego", "apple": "manzana"}
```

And then retrieve the translation:

```
d.get("fire", "No translation")
```

BTW. on python.org you will find awesome documentation on how to learn Python:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

I presume that you should start here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers